# How can I program a switch to monitor traffic, classify and block it?

Tags: routes

I'm working on a project in which I need to do something like, I'll monitor and collect traffic passing through a switch, then classify it based upon port number, packet size and maybe IP range too. Then I want to display this on a web page. The web page will show real time traffic passing through a switch and classified. Now, if I want to drop certain type of packets, I'll just click on the block button on the web page and I'll command the switch to block the packets with particular port number, packet size and IP range.

I want to know, if it's possible. And if it is possible how can I do so?? What should I use,  GNS3 Mininet or something else. I'll appreciate as many suggestions as I Can.

I have tried to find solutions to this but have failed. I'm hoping to find if this project can be implemented.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: This is off-topic, as 1) it's very broad; 2) it's a recommendation question; 3) it's opinion-soliciting; and 4) there's no programming question.

Comment: Also please be mindful of tagging. [tag:switch-statement] has nothing to do with your question. I removed that tag, accordingly. [tag:routes] is unrelated too, but every question needs at least one tag...

Answer (score 0):

One idea you can try is to use the OpenVSwitch instance from Mininet to extract the OpenFlow entries which contain packet information that can be useful to you (src IP, dst IP, port nr, etc.).

To do this, in the Mininet console run the following command on your switch component which will extract the OpenFlow entries in the text file, then you can process the text file and extract the information you need:

```
ovs-ofctl dump-flows s1 > entries.txt # check the documentation for exact syntax
```

You can trigger this command periodically with a timer and then process the data every time it is generated to display it in your app